# Running two socket servers on same port

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, vhosts

I have three servers

1. Main server - which listens to all HTTP request
2. Socket Server 1 : Listen to X types of socket request
3. Socket Server 2 : Listen to Y types of socket request

I want to run all three servers using same IP:Port combination and all three servers have different hostname. I have updated local DNS i.e. `/etc/hosts` to resolve all three domain names to same IP, take `127.0.0.1` for instance.

I am using `VHost` to resolve the requests on basis of hostname and directing request to appropriate server. Here is the code for that :

```
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');


var mainServer =  <hostname1> ;
var socketServer1 = <hostname2> ;
var socketServer2 = <hostname3>;


var server = https.createServer(<options>, app);

server.listen(<somePort>,function(){
    console.log('VHost running');
});

var mainApp = require('./app.js');
var socketServerApp1 = require('./socketServer1');
var socketServerApp2 = require('./socketServer2');

app.use(vhost(mainServer, mainApp));
app.use(vhost(socketServer1, socketServerApp1(server)));
app.use(vhost(socketServer2, socketServerApp2(server)));
```

The problem I am facing in above code is, if I try to run both socket servers, the browser throws an error like :

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://socketServer1:8443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=qlSXz3os5eDI8c_EAAAC' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

But if there is only one socket server running at a time, then things works fine for that socket server i.e. if I comment one of app.use like :

```
app.use(vhost(mainServer, mainApp));
app.use(vhost(socketServer1, socketServerApp1(server)));
//  app.use(vhost(socketServer1, socketServerApp2(server)));
```

Is it not possible to run two socket servers on same IP:Port combination?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a proxy like nginx which could forward each incoming connection destined for a particular hostname to a different port on the one server.  Then, you'd have three listeners, one for each, all listening on different ports.  Other than that, you will likely have to simulate that same functionality on your own server by having one listener on the desired port that then spreads out the requests to the right handlers.

Comment: is it necessary that you have the two different websocket servers? from that piece of code it seems like both listen to the same domain. Maybe `namespaces` in socket.io could solve your problem.

Comment: What you are suggesting is to merge socketServer1 and socketServer2?

Comment: well yes you could merge and use namespaces, say you have one page `/realtime` or other pages below that `/realtime/deals` that emits other events and must be handled differently from the rest of the website. you can do in socket.io `.of('/realtime').on(<event>,<callback>)` and so on, separating it this way from other common events and you dont need to have two different ws servers for the same application, i wont say that can't have it because apparently you can proxy requests as mentioned above, but in my opinion its simpler and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that both socket servers were having separate listners, which was causing the error. Moving socket listner to vhost App fixes the problem . Following is the code :

```
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var socketio = require('socket.io');


var mainServer =  <hostname1> ;
var socketServer1 = <hostname2> ;
var socketServer2 = <hostname3>;


var server = https.createServer(<options>, app);
var io = socketio.listen(server);

server.listen(<somePort>,function(){
    console.log('VHost running');
});

var mainApp = require('./app.js');
var socketServerApp1 = require('./socketServer1');
var socketServerApp2 = require('./socketServer2');

app.use(vhost(mainServer, mainApp));
app.use(vhost(socketServer1, socketServerApp1(io)));
app.use(vhost(socketServer2, socketServerApp2(io)));
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your entire solution?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the same code on production too. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: The usage of your two socket servers inside your main server. I have a similar challenge and I'm trying to implement your solution.